# 7z: the number of files in "Scanning the drive" is way larger than the number of "Files read from disk"

Tags: 7zip

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.
So I wanted to back up a folder (minecraft world), installed p7zip (p7zip-full and p7zip-rar) and tried running it.
There was no errors, but I notice something strange. Basically the number of files in "Scanning the drive" is way larger (by 87), than the number of "Files read from disk".

```
7z a novoterskaya-14.11.21.7z Novoterskaya/

7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,2 CPUs AMD A6-5400K APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics    (610F01),ASM,AES-NI)

Scanning the drive:
20 folders, 1093 files, 1989481565 bytes (1898 MiB)

Creating archive: novoterskaya-14.11.21.7z

Items to compress: 1113


Files read from disk: 1006
Archive size: 1040453839 bytes (993 MiB)
Everything is Ok
```

This is probably not something awful, but I'd like to be sure I'm not losing any files. Also, just out of curiosity, I'm really interested to why it happens.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting instead: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: understood, changed it